Question about Kantorovich-Rubinstein distance
When the cost function is a metric, i.e., $c(x,y)=d(x,y)$ on $X=Y$, the optimal transportation cost
$$\mathcal{T}_d(\mu,\nu)= \inf_{\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)} \int_{X\times X} d(x,y)d\pi(x,y)$$
is also called Kantorovich-Rubinstein distance.
Let $X=Y$ be a Polish space and let $d$ be a lower semi-continuous distance on $X$. Let $\mu$, $\nu$ and $\sigma$ be three Borel (nonnegative) measures on $X$, such that $\mu[X]=\nu[X]<+\infty$, $\sigma[X]<+\infty$ and $\mu$, $\nu$ and $\sigma$ are all absolutely continuous w.r.t to the Lebesgue measure.
Now I want to find an example where $\mathcal{T}_d(\mu+\sigma,\nu+\sigma)<\mathcal{T}_d(\mu,\nu)$, but I don't have any good idea, can anybody help me?

This is not possible, you will always have equality.

In general, for the $p$-Wasserstein distance we have
$$W_{p}(\mu + \sigma, \nu + \sigma) \le W_{p}(\mu, \nu)$$
with the above holding with equality when $p=1$ as the comment suggests. I will first prove the special case that is of interest to you and then prove the general statement for future reference.
To show that $W_1(\mu + \sigma, \nu + \sigma) = W_1(\mu, \nu)$, consider the dual formulation of the 1-Wasserstein distance from Kantorovich and Rubinstein:
$$W_1(\mu, \nu) = \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int_{X \times X} c(x, y)d\pi(x, y) = \sup_{f \in Lip_1(X)} \int_{X} f(x) d(\mu - \nu)(x)$$
where $Lip_1({X})$ is the set of 1-Lipschitz continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $c$. It is easy to see that
$$W_1(\mu + \sigma, \nu + \sigma) = \sup_{f \in Lip_1(X)} \int_{X} f(x) d(\mu + \sigma - (\nu + \sigma))(x) \\ = \sup_{f \in Lip_1(X)} \int_{X} f(x) d(\mu - \nu)(x) = W_1(\mu, \nu)$$
Now, to show that $W_p(\mu + \sigma, \nu + \sigma) \le W_{p}(\mu, \nu)$ for any $p \in [1, + \infty]$, let $\pi^{*} \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$ be the optimal coupling that achieves $W_p(\mu,  \nu)$ and define $\pi_{\sigma} \triangleq (id \times id)_{\# \sigma}$ as the diagonal coupling $\pi_{\sigma}(A \times B) = \sigma(A \cap B)$ for any $A, B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ where $\mathcal{B}(X)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$.
Let $\Pi(\mu + \sigma, \nu + \sigma) \ni \pi' \triangleq \pi^{*} + \pi_{\sigma}$. We start by checking this is indeed a valid coupling:
$$\small \pi'(A \times X) = (\pi^* + \pi_{\sigma})(A \times X) = \pi^*(A \times X) + \pi_{\sigma}(A \times X) = \mu(A) + \sigma(A \cap X) = \mu(A) + \sigma(A) \\ \small \pi'(X \times B) = (\pi^* + \pi_{\sigma})(X \times B) = \pi^*(X \times B) + \pi_{\sigma}(X \times B) = \nu(B) + \sigma(X \cap B) = \mu(B) + \sigma(B)$$
where $A, B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$. Consider the following integral under $\pi'$:
$$\int_{X \times X}{c(x, y)^p \pi'(x, y)} = \int_{X \times X} c(x, y)^p d\pi^{*}(x, y) + \int_{X \times X} c(x, y)^p d\pi_{\sigma}(x, y) \\ = W_{p}(\mu, \nu)^p + \int_{X}{c(x, x)^p d\sigma(x)} = W_{p}(\mu, \nu)^p$$
Taking the infimum over couplings, which corresponds to the $p$-th power of the $p$-Wasserstein distance we have
$$W_{p}(\mu + \sigma, \nu + \sigma)^p = \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu + \sigma, \nu + \sigma)} \int_{X \times X}{c(x, y)^p d\pi(x, y)} \le W_{p}(\mu, \nu)^p$$
and by taking the $p$-th root we arrive at
$$W_{p}(\mu + \sigma, \nu + \sigma) \le W_{p}(\mu, \nu)$$
